# How to list posts of a given format

Tags: wp-query, url-rewriting

I want to create new urls in my wordpress that list posts of a given format and category. I thought the url structure would make sense to be like this:
/[post-format]/[category], i.e.: /videos/technology, /videos/kittens ...

So I created a plugin to add the rewrite rules, it looks like this:
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );
function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^(videos|audios|gallery)/(.*)/?$',
        'index.php?format=$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]',
        'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26388_query_vars' );
function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'format';
    $query_vars[] = 'category_name';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

It kinda works, but only kinda. I don't know how to filter the posts by format and I'd like the archive template to be loaded instead of the regular category template list.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you try custom page? page-{slug}.php ?

Comment: you mean instead of index.php? that would mean to create a new page in the root of the wordpress project, which I don't like. I prefer just to modify the plugins and templates content and keep the "core" clean :)